# How to get mod-rewrites and php 301 redirects?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was hoping someone could also guide me on setting a redirect on a php site pcs4cheap.ca ....I tried to do mod re-writes through the .htaccess, works fine but prevents any othe login or admin page to open !

Any other way I could achieve this would be much appreciated =)

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question:

[How best to redirect a webpage without using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875318/how-best-to-redirect-a-webpage-without-using-javascript/875328#875328)

In PHP it's done by using the header() function.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
exit;
```